# Spring boot logging issues with macOS High Sierra

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, server, jetty

I have upgraded to macOS High Sierra today and I tried to start the Tomcat server (from Eclipse IDE) which has got a Spring Boot application, but it **simply show** the line

`:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)`

as shown in the screen shot.

I tried to google the issue and found the problem [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7680039), it looked initially like a Network related issue, but it it is NOT.

The screen shot below also shows the Network default settings (from Eclipse IDE preferences), which I have NOT changed so far.

[image]

I could replicate the same **logging issue** with a different server i.e., I tried to start the Jetty server (to double check that it is NOT Tomcat specific issue), the log has been provided below:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2017-12-08 15:08:53.038:INFO:oejshC.ABC:main: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-08 15:09:34.547:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-12-08 15:09:34.547:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-12-08 15:09:34.549:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 600000ms
2017-12-08 15:09:34.576:INFO:oejshC.ABC:main: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-08 15:09:34.663:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@73846619{/ABC,file:////jetty-distribution-9.4.6/webapps/ABC/,AVAILABLE}{/ABC}
2017-12-08 15:09:34.700:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6690258a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9999}
2017-12-08 15:09:34.701:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @60553ms
```

**UPDATE:**

I could find that there is a **logging issue with Spring boot** (look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/196)), but there the solution relates to Ansi-Console plugin, which I am not using.

**NOTE:**

The other important point is that I could actually **print** the statements to **Console** of the both the servers using **`System.out.println`**

You can have a look at the issue that I have created [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11297) on the spring-boot github project.

Comment: Could be many reasons that happens. Try running Spring Boot with debug logging enabled. This might give you a better idea of where everything stops.

Comment: I lowered the logging level to DEBUG/TRACE, surprisingly, no additional logging apart from above.

Comment: Hm, you can always try TRACE level next :)

Comment: The Jetty deploy shows a webapp deployed successfully at the context `/ABC`, so go use `http://localhost:9999/ABC/` and it should respond.

Comment: @javaguy the format of the logging output on the Jetty run seems to show the default logging behavior of Jetty's `StdErrLog`, which defaults to INFO level and above for the named Jetty Loggers `org.eclipse.jetty.*` being output to STDERR (aka `System.err`)